# How to replace the last specific instance of a text string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In a sentence like `everybody! eat! eat eat eat!` I only need the last `!` to be replaced, not the others.

```
q = raw_input("English: ")
qq = str(q.isspace())
e = ''
while q != e:
    q =q.replace("i", "ee")
    q =q.replace("!", ". bork bork bork!")
    q =q.replace("th","z")
    print q
    q = raw_input("English: ")
```

Comment: What if there's more text after it?

Comment: Is this homework? Looks very much like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229269/python-replacing-issue that was just posted

Answer (score 3):

```
s = "everybody! eat! eat eat eat!"  
s[::-1].replace("!", "?", 1)[::-1]
```

results in

```
everybody! eat! eat eat eat?
```

**Edit:**

Works for words, too:

```
s[::-1].replace("tae", "knird", 1)[::-1]
# => 'everybody! eat! eat eat drink!'
```

**Edit 2:**

I think you get the idea:

```
s[::-1].replace("eat"[::-1], "drink"[::-1], 1)[::-1]
# => 'everybody! eat! eat eat drink!'
```

Comment: Thanks brohan! I really appreciate it <3

Answer (score 2):

**Updated**:

Using [rstrip()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=rstrip#str.rstrip):

```
s = "everybody! eat! eat eat eat!"  
s[:-1]+s[-1].rstrip('!')+'. bork bork bork!' # updated
```

gives:

```
'everybody! eat! eat eat eat. bork bork bork!'
```

assuming there's nothing after the `!` (wasn't really specified either way). `rstrip()` will gobble up the trailing `!` and we concatenate the replacement text to the end of the string.

The **update** prevents multiple trailing `!!!` all being striped, using slice notation we only strip the last character if it's a `!`.

*Previous solution*:

```
 s.rstrip('!')+'. bork bork bork!'
```

would have gobbled up multiple trailing `!!!`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use regular expressions:

```
s = 'everybody! eat! eat eat eat!'

import re
print re.sub(r'!([^!]*)$', r'?\1', s)
```

Using only string functions:

```
p = s.rpartition('!')
if p[1]:
    s = p[0] + '?' + p[2]
print s
```

Comment: Why the no-comment down vote? Upvoting to compensate for chicken BS!

Comment: downvotes without explanation are worthless, *no one* gets anything out of them.

Answer (score 0):

The string method `replace` takes an optional argument letting you decide how many times you want to replace. As you want to replace your last one, just reverse the string

```
>>> s = "hey! hey! hey! hey!"
>>> s[::-1].replace("!","?",1)[::-1]
'hey! hey! hey! hey?'
```

Note that it works only if you replace **one** single character, of course...